# Is there a way in java to group specific type of files from a folder based on the file name and add them alone?

Tags: java, file-io

I wanted to know is there any specific method to filter file names and add specific files alone to a file array based on its prefix???

for example: 
File: A_error_log.txt,A.txt,A.fasta,B.fasta,B_error_log.txt
From the above file list i just want to move the A type files to a folder and B type files to another folder.

A standard solution would be,get the list of files,then using get name check them for specific file name prefixes and add them.

I wanted to know is there any other method already present 4r this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tolerate an extra external dependency the filefilter package of [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-summary.html) has many premade filters for this kind of operations, what you want is easy to do with the [WildcardFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html):

```
 File dir = new File(".");
 FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("A*");
 File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(files[i]);
 }
```

There are many other filters, and a set of "logic" filters (AndFileFilter, OrFileFilter and NotFileFilter) that allow you to string several filters together.

Should you decide to use Commons IO, in the [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) package there are a number of very interesting methods to move files around that also handle the case that a file has to be moved to another files system.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html). An [example is here.](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory) All you need is Java. No external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has many ready-made [file filters](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-frame.html), you can  combine those filters, apply `AND` and `OR` operations on them. Also, it has many good [file operations](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) , using these filters.